# Parallelize computation with map and reduce in Spark when using BinaryClassificationMetrics?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, recommendation-engine

I am trying to parallelize the computation of AUC in Spark by using map and reduce instead of a for loop.

However, as I have another RDD `sc.parallelize(recModelPredictionsAndLabels)` and I cannot use an RDD inside a transformation as nested RDD transformations are not allowed.

`BinaryClassificationMetrics()` supports only RDD as an input.

Here's my current code:

```
def computeRecommenderAUC(
  trainData: RDD[Rating],
  testData: RDD[Rating],
  bUserArtistMap: Broadcast[scala.collection.Map[Int, Set[Int]]],
  rank: Int,
  numIterations: Int,
  lambda: Double,
  alpha: Double
): Double = {

  // Initialize the recommender model using Spark's ALS algorithm
  val model = ALS.trainImplicit(
    ratings = trainData,
    rank = rank,
    iterations = numIterations,
    lambda = lambda,
    alpha = alpha
  )

  // Get the unique user IDs for the users in the test data and create a broadcast variable
  val bTestData = sc.broadcast(testData.map(r => r.user).distinct().collect())

  // Calculate the AUC in parallel
  val aucSum = sc.parallelize(bTestData.value)
    .map { user =>
      val actualArtists = bUserArtistMap.value(user)
      val recModelRecommendations = model.recommendProducts(user, 100)

      val recModelPredictionsAndLabels = recModelRecommendations.map {
        case Rating(_, artist, rating) =>
          if (actualArtists.contains(artist)) (rating, 1.0)
          else (rating, 0.0)
      }
      
      val recModelMetrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(
        sc.parallelize(recModelPredictionsAndLabels)
      )
      recModelMetrics.areaUnderROC
    }
    .reduce(_ + _)

  // Calculate the final average AUC
  aucSum / bTestData.value.length
}
```

Which results in the following error

```
This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases:
(1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```